# ffmpeg multiple process in background

Tags: ffmpeg

Immortal set ffmpeg process in while but only one process in background. Is the any way to set ffmpeg command to more than 1 process ?

> immortal -r -1 ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

Just use basic unix to send processes in the background:

```
ffmpeg <some parameters> &>/dev/null &
ffmpeg <some other parameters> &>/dev/null
```

Comment: It was meant to read like

<first ffmpeg cmd line> &>/dev/null &
<second ffmpeg cmd line> &>/dev/null

and not literally 'ffmpeg-1'